# Intern tests: cannot run local Firefox and Chrome tests together, Chrome will timeout and hang

Tags: gruntjs, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, intern

I am trying to run functional tests with intern for Chrome and Firefox.

First, Chromedriver would not wait long enough for the page to load and element transitions to end and become visible, so I added `sleep()`'s in a few places and used `pollUntil()` to wait for the initial page load.  None of this was necessary for Firefox.

I am able to run my tests on either Firefox, which all pass, or Chrome, which all pass half the time.  But if I list both browsers in my Intern configuration, Chrome will fail all tests, the Chrome window will be frozen, and the chrome and chromedriver processes will remain running, detached from selenium webdriver process when I stop the webdriver from command line. The error I usually get from webdriver if I wait long enough is

> Exception: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000

I am running local selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar and chromedriver v2.16 (Chrome v44, up to date) with Intern 3.0, on Windows7 64.

From what I've read, Chrome has issues with getting the active window, and when Firefox pops up, the Chrome processes are lost. I don't know if that would be an issue with the Firefox window or just other Chrome windows, though. Maybe it's bugging out when get() [happens](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1082&q=webdriver%20renderer&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary). Or just [not loading](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=402&q=wait&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary) all the way.

Is there anything I can do to run them together? Or will I have to run each browser separately until/if the chromedriver issues are taken care of? Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The test that fail are able to get past `get()`, `pollUntil()`, `findElementById()`, but have trouble on the `click()`. After the window freezes, my tests timeout but are not able to finish completely and cleanup, i guess.

Comment: Well, it seems running these tests with grunt was part of the issue. Using just intern-runner, the test are now ending correctly (when they fail) so that I am able to enter another command, at least. And the chrome/chromedriver processes are not floating around by themselves apart from selenium with my chrome window frozen. Still getting errors that don't happen with Firefox though.

Comment: Nevermind, Chrome is still freezing and the processes are still hanging around when using intern-runner.  But only when testing firefox and chrome together (and only 3 tests each).  Chrome times out unless run by itself.

Comment: I was able to run 3 tests multiple times, without using sleep() or pollUntil(), on Chrome and Firefox together after I closed the main Chrome browser I was using and the 2 chrome crash handler processes. I will continue to see what went wrong with some of my other tests that timed out, but this is a start.